# snowflake python connector not returning results properly

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch the results of a snowflake query using python connector. I am not getting the expected results

the sql command in snowflake is

```
select
    operator_statistics:io:external_bytes_scanned::number external_bytes_scanned
from table(get_query_operator_stats('01aacd75-0504-5897-000d-dd0700c50b36'))
where operator_type='ExternalScan'
```

[image]

The above i am trying using python connector

The below is through python connectot

```
    sql = f"""
        select
            operator_statistics:io:external_bytes_scanned::number external_bytes_scanned
        from table(get_query_operator_stats('01aacd75-0504-5897-000d-dd0700c50b36'))
        where operator_type='ExternalScan'
    """


    con = snowflake.connector.connect(
        account="xxxxxxxxxx",
        user="yyyyyyyyyy",
        password="xxxxxxxxxxx",
        warehouse="ttttttttttt",
        database="tttt"
    )

    try:
        res = con.execute_string(sql)
        for x in res:
            print(x.__dict__)
        con.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    finally:
        con.close()
```

the below is what i get

```
   "__dict__": {
      "_connection": "<snowflake.connector.connection.SnowflakeConnection object at 0x7f343eb24610>",
      "_errorhandler": "<function Error.default_errorhandler at 0x7f34401a20e0>",
      "messages": [],
      "_timebomb": null,
      "_description": [
        [
          "EXTERNAL_BYTES_SCANNED",
          0,
          null,
          null,
          38,
          0,
          true
        ]
      ],
      "_column_idx_to_name": null,
      "_sfqid": "01aacee6-0504-5985-000d-dd0700c580ba",
      "_sqlstate": null,
      "_total_rowcount": 1,
      "_sequence_counter": -1,
      "_request_id": "f93d6def-9071-4d5a-9154-59c73e636ac4",
      "_is_file_transfer": false,
      "_timestamp_output_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZHTZM",
      "_timestamp_ltz_output_format": "",
      "_timestamp_ntz_output_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3",
      "_timestamp_tz_output_format": "",
      "_date_output_format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "_time_output_format": "HH24:MI:SS",
      "_timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
      "_binary_output_format": "HEX",
      "_result": "<snowflake.connector.json_result.JsonResult object at 0x7f343e7de1d0>",
      "_use_dict_result": false,
      "_json_result_class": "<class 'snowflake.connector.json_result.JsonResult'>",
      "_arraysize": 1,
      "_lock_canceling": "<unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7f343eb3e540>",
      "_first_chunk_time": 1678278121805,
      "_log_max_query_length": 80,
      "_query_result_format": "json"
    },
```

I can see something related to the query results as

```
     "_description": [
        [
          "EXTERNAL_BYTES_SCANNED",
          0,
          null,
          null,
          38,
          0,
          true
        ]
      ],
```

but here is dont see any `315139374775` as external_bytes_scanned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you see in the "_description" are the result set metadata. If you want to get the actual result returned by the query you can do something like:

```python
try:
    res = con.execute_string(sql)
    for cursor in res:
        for row in cursor:
            print(row[0])
finally:
        con.close()
```